# Exposing Kong Admin API to internal network

Tags: networking, microservices, amazon-vpc, kong

We have a Kong Gateway running within a VPC in AWS.  Currently, the Admin API for the Kong Gateway is restricted to only localhost traffic using

```
export KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN="127.0.0.1:8001"
export KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL="127.0.0.1:8444"
```

We'd like to allow microservices within the same VPC to register their own routes when they get deployed.  In order to do this we need to open up the `KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN` to other machines within the VPC.  However, we don't want any machine outside the network to be able to access it.

I'm pretty new to networking and did not find the Kong docs very clear on how to do this.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Can you say a little more about what sort of configuration of Kong you are hoping your microservices will be able to perform?